# Выполнение кода после окончания анимации

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема заключается в том что скрытие формы выполняется сразу, а не после анимации. Как добиться того что бы после окончания анимации выполнялось скрытие формы

```
DoubleAnimation HideBlindWindow = new DoubleAnimation(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - Blind.Width, SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
DoubleAnimation HideTimeWindow = new DoubleAnimation(0.9, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(140), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);

blind.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, HideBlindWindow);
timeWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, HideTimeWindow);

// как сделать чтобы эти действия выполнялись после окончания анимации
blind.Hide();
timeWindow.Hide();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте Completed event для анимации. Подробнее на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx). В вашем случае:

```
anim.Completed += new EventHandler(anim_Completed);

private void anim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //здесь ваш код после завершения анимации
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваша анимация длится 150 миллисекунд? Ну так подождите эти самые 150 миллисекунд перед тем, как выходить:

```
blind.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, HideBlindWindow);
timeWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, HideTimeWindow);

await Task.Delay(150);

blind.Hide();
timeWindow.Hide();
```

Вам придётся переделать ваш метод в `async`.