# Переход на новую страницу после загрузки ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar Name="pb" Width="500" Height="50" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
```

И две страницы WPF: firstPage и secondPage

У ProgressBar есть метод, который вызывается при загрузки страницы:

```
public void DownloadLine()
{
    Duration dur = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    DoubleAnimation dbani = new DoubleAnimation(300.0, dur);
    pb.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, dbani);
}
```

Вопрос: как перейти на secondPage после загрузки ProgressBar?

Comment: Странная имитация бурной деятельности. Можно подписаться на событие завершения анимации: `Completed`

Comment: Решил свой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675296/Выполнение-кода-после-окончания-анимации